# how to log bandwidth usage on windows 8

Tags: windows, network-monitoring, windows-8, cellular

My Father has a Verizon jet pack (hotspot card).  He is seeing 100+ MB spikes on the Verizon data usage report a few times a day.   On July 4th the verizon data usage report online shows 6 GB were used 3 times 6:02 am, 12:02 pm, and 6:02 pm.  Over 18 GB in one day.   He is a very light internet user.  A few emails per day, no videos.

I am running tcpview on his computer to see how many MB each process is using.  Over 4 days we are not seeing anything strange.   TCPVIEW does not seem to agree with the verizon data usage report.   TCPVIEW only shows total values.  The verizon report gives totals at random times.

```
date        time    MB
07/17/2014  4:02 AM 123.95
07/17/2014  3:55 AM 0.07
07/17/2014  2:41 AM 0.70
07/17/2014  1:50 AM 0.36
07/17/2014  1:50 AM 0.18
07/16/2014  8:41 PM 65.92
07/16/2014  2:41 PM 59.24
07/16/2014  8:41 AM 117.84
07/16/2014  7:16 AM 32.51
07/16/2014  7:04 AM 0.00
07/15/2014  7:29 PM 5.17
07/15/2014  6:36 PM 5.17
07/15/2014  6:30 PM 0.06
07/15/2014  6:04 PM 1.62
07/15/2014  4:50 PM 47.70
07/15/2014  3:03 PM 2.48
07/15/2014  11:30 AM    78.56
07/15/2014  11:25 AM    0.23
07/15/2014  11:22 AM    2.29
07/15/2014  5:22 AM 107.32
```

What tool would you recommend to track down the details of these data usage spikes?  He is using Windows 8.  If you know of a way to stop these spikes, please tell me.  His internet setup using a verizon jet pack (hot spot) needs to stay under 15 GB per month.

Comment: I'd download a bandwidth monitor with a logging capability... probably the only way to get a definitive answer.

Comment: Is there a bandwidth monitor that you would recommend that I can keep running all day, and if possible, not create huge logs?

Comment: I don't use Windows 8, so I can't help you out with that.  Check the Google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[As explained here](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/43713/how-to-monitor-the-bandwidth-consumption-of-individual-applications/) you can use netbalancer to both monitor the usage on specific applications as well as log, and can limit total usage either system wide or for specific applications as well. Free version should be sufficient. Also, this would probably be better suited for the super user community, rather than the Sysadmin one.